# php get array values as new variable for ldap

Tags: php, arrays, variables, ldap

suppose I got an array like this:

```
array ([0] => array([0]=>dog [1]=>cat))
```

How am I able to get just only "dog" and "cat" to store them in variables? I would like to use them for a further search. Like okay I find one array animals with these values, take each value to find arrays which describes the dog and cat races.

my try failed:

```
echo '<pre>';
foreach($result as $animals){

for($i=0;i<$animals;i++){
$find = animals[i];
$filter = "(objectClass=*)";
$show = array("race","subrace");
$animalSearch = ldap_search($ds, $find, $filter, $show) or die "...";
$animalInfos = ldap_get_entries($ds,$animalSearch) or die"shit";
print_r($animalInfos);
}
```

Comment: You're missing `$` is many places. `animals[i]` should be `$animals[$i]`... and `for($i=0;i<$animals;i++){` should be `for($i=0; $i < count($animals); $i++){`... c'mon dude.

Comment: Sidenote: `or die"shit";`. Don't ever do this. I know it's funny and I know you will think you'll clean it up before it hits production, but there will be a time where you didn't and you're in a room full of important people when your demo is going wrong and then there is vulgar text all over the screen and all the people wonder why in the name they hired you to create their software. Just do yourself a favor and write meaningful messages.

Comment: thx. i'm new to ldap and php. But it seems like it doesn't work either

Comment: No problem - your input is a multidimensional array; meaning it is an array within an array. This isn't a bad thing but can make looping more difficult. *If you can*, try to simplify this into a simple, flat array. This will make looping through it easier. Do you have control over this array or is it coming from outside your system? Try and get it to `array([0]=>dog [1]=>cat)`. That way, you can use a simple `foreach ($input as $animal) { ...`

Comment: it's generated automatically by searching within ldap. every search result comes in multidimensional arrays, because the root has several subtrees in which i have to search. maybe i think the problem is that i really just can't store the arrays value as a string in a variable. otherwise the search function wouldn't fail, because it function right before this loop.

Comment: I see; multidimensional arrays it is then. What do you get if you run 
`foreach ($result as $animals){
    foreach ($animals as $animal){
        echo $animal;
    }
}`

Comment: 502 bad gateway haha

Comment: i guess i have to learn more about multi arrays and looping through them. thanks anyways

Comment: @wateroomatt thanks for your advices. after struggling with my brain, code and your advices i finally got the solution. i'll post it here..

Answer (score 0):

as waterloomatt said, accessing multi arrays are the key and i think i pretended his suggestions wrong. finally i got a solution:

```
$filter = "(description=just animals)";
$attr = array("name");
$search = ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filter, $attr) or die("not successfull");

$info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $search) or die ("no entries");

echo '<pre>';
foreach($info as $animals => $values){

          foreach($values as $newDn) {
              for ($i = 0; $i < count($newDn); $i++) {
                  echo $newDn[$i];
                  $RaceFilter = "(objectClass=*)";
                  $justthese = array("name", "color");
                  $raceSearch = ldap_search($ds, $newDn[$i], $RaceFilter, $justthese) or die("can't search");
                  $race = ldap_get_entries($ds, $raceSearch) or die ("no entries");

                  print_r($race);

              }
          }
    }
```